# service implementation pattern

Tags: android, web-services, service

ok I have this application which needs to send periodic updates to a web-service, I have done a fair amount of research and I've come up with two service implementation patterns.

1. Implement a service with a thread, the periodic update time may vary therefore, I will put the thread to sleep with the required time-interval, then call the web-service again. I also need to update an activity, therefore will be using a broadcast receiver or a messenger.
2. Use a Service with a schedule timer/alarm manager, wake the system and use intent services coupled with a broadcast receiver.

Which would be the best approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I would go with the #2 option :

1. Create an `IntentService` to do the update.
2. Register a `BroadcastReceiver` with `IntentFilter`(s) and start the `IntentService` from it.
3. Use `AlarmManager` to `Broadcast` the registered action at the required time intervals.

I prefer this method because :

1. It is a very flexible pattern : You can start the service anytime by registering the same receiver for different actions like network connection changes, system boot changes etc.,
2. It keeps the logic loosely coupled from other parts of the app.
3. There is no hassle of managing threads. You get it for free by using `IntentService`
4. It is more android-ish way of solving this problem.

Answer (score 0):

The main difference would be that a background service can be shut down by the user and then you won't get any more updates.  If you register events with the AlarmManager, then you control when/if these events take place.  If the user shuts down your app and goes into a task manager and shuts down any running services related to your app, the AlarmManager is still going to wake up and send a message that your BroadcastReceiver will receive.

Comment: Not strictly true on later versions of Android (v3+). If the user uses Force Stop from the app manager to stop an app then no application components will be activated until the user manually starts the app again. I may be wrong but as far as I understand it, even receivers registered in the manifest won't get called.

Comment: so which method would you recommend? if none of the above, do you have a better way of implementing it?

Comment: @Hades : I'm not sure if your comment was directed to me or Rich. To answer it anyway, Rich is basically correct although as I mentioned, if a user of later Android versions stops the app manually, things won't work again until they manually start it again. This is unavoidable with any method. The answer from 500865, however, is the approach I would take and I do use a similar model for daily downloads of user data.